# Jquery dual effect

Tags: jquery, dialog, jquery-dialog, jquery-effects

Hej,

I am facing difficulty with applying dual effect to my dialog effects. I know this question is replicated, but I am not able to figure out what am I doing wrong here.

below is my normal code with slide in effect on Open dialog box, and "puff" effect on the closing dialog box. Both codes are working fine.

Open dialogBox

```
$( "#dialogWindow" ).dialog( "open" );

$( "#dialogWindow" ).effect( "slide", {direction: 'up', distance:300} , 330 );
```

Closing dialogBox

```
var option = {}; 

$( "#dialogWindow" ). effect( "puff", options, 400 );  

setTimeout(function() { $("#dialogWindow").dialog('close'); }, 300 )
```

I want to apply fadeIn effect (follow by slide effect) before the slide in dialog open, And change the closing effect from "puff" to fadeOut. I am using the following code,

Open dialog box

```
$( "#dialogWindow" ).dialog( "open" ).fadeIn(3000).effect( "slide", {direction: 'up', distance:300} , 330 ).dequeue();
```

Closing dialog box

```
$("#dialogWindow").dialog('close').fadeOut(3000).dequeue();
```

There is something wrong with the queue, as it applies the effect on the 2nd attempt to open / close.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

My requirement was to fade In the popup, and then apply the slide effect.
Fortunately the JQuery dialog use fade In / Fade Out effect by default. All I had to use was show & hide options. And then call the effect after dialog open.

Below is the code for calling dialog. I am loading dialog on the click event of class "product3"

```
$( "#product3" ).dialog({

    autoOpen: false,

    resizable: false,             

    modal: true,


    show: {
             effect: 'fade',
             duration: 900
        },

    hide: {
            effect: 'fade',
            duration: 900
        },

});



   $(".product3").click(function(){

      $( "#product3" ).dialog( "open" );

      $( "#product3" ).dialog( "option", "width", 1215 );

      $( "#product3" ).dialog( "option", "height", 530 );

   $( "#product3" ).effect( "slide", {direction: 'up', distance:300} , 330 );

    });
```